# How to get rid of ESLint error <template v-for> key should be placed on the <template> tag?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using NuxtJS with Vuetify in an app. When showing a table of records with `v-data-table`, I want to show a badge if the item.isActive is true. For that, I am looping over `<template>` inside `<tr>`. Whenever I am providing key to the `<template>` tag I am getting `'<template v-for>' cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead`. When I am trying to key the `<td>`, I am getting `<template v-for> key should be placed on the <template> tag.` This is faced in VSCode with ESLint

1st Error

[image]

2nd Error

[image]

Implementation:

```
  <v-data-table :items="items">
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      <tr>
        <template v-for="(header, index) in headers">
          <td v-if="header.value === 'isActive'" :key="index">
            <v-badge bordered content="" offset-x="-10" color="'#64b54d'" />
          </td>
          <td
            v-else
            :key="index"
          >
            {{ item[header.value] }}
          </td>
        </template>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-wood-q4mc5h?file=/pages/home.vue:11-585

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-v-for-template-key-on-child.html this is the rule you need to disable, i.e. put `"vue/no-v-for-template-key-on-child": "off"` in the `eslintconfig>rules` part of the package.json. however, if your VS Code is  still complaining, that'd be the work of one of the VueJS plugins - you might have to talk to the author about it

Comment: may I ask why are you using `template` tag here? why not to put v-for on your `<tr>`?

Comment: @miro because you cannot use v-for and v-if on the same element.

Answer (score 10):

I've had similar situations and for me, this is what it boils down to (although the error does not say that specifically):

There is no reason to use a `<template>` tag in that situation. Putting `v-for` on the child inside the `<template>` would give you the exact same output.

Here are some screenshots to clarify:

1. Here we have an error.

[image: Here we have an error]

2. Adding a `v-if` on the child could for example be a reason for using `<template>` (`v-if` should not be used on the same element as `v-for`). Now the error is gone.

[image: No error anymore]

3. Or we simply loop the element inside the `<template>` tag and the error goes away.

[image: No error anymore]

Answer (score 2):

This error is frequently encountered in DL tags.

#### Pattern A: Key on inner element

```html
  <dl>
    <template v-for="(faq, index) in props.faqData">
      <dt :key="`dt-${index}`">
        {{ faq.question }}
      </dt>
      <dd :key="`dd-${index}`">
        {{ faq.answer }}
      </dd>
    </template>
  </dl>
```

This gives `[plugin:vite:vue] <template v-for> key should be placed on the <template> tag.` in vue3.

#### Pattern B: Key on template tag

```html
  <dl>
    <template v-for="(faq, index) in props.faqData" :key="`item-${index}`">
      <dt>
        {{ faq.question }}
      </dt>
      <dd>
        {{ faq.answer }}
      </dd>
    </template>
  </dl>
```

This gives `ESLint: '<template v-for>' cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead.(vue/no-v-for-template-key)`.
But it seems to work fine.

#### Pattern C: Wrapped by div tag

```html
  <dl>
    <div v-for="(faq, index) in props.faqData" :key="`dl-${index}`">
      <dt>
        {{ faq.question }}
      </dt>
      <dd>
        {{ faq.answer }}
      </dd>
    </div>
  </dl>
```

No error occurs in this case. However, this HTML is incorrect.

### My solution: Surpress the warning

```html
  <dl>
    <!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-v-for-template-key -->
    <template v-for="(faq, index) in props.faqData" :key="`item-${index}`">
      <dt>
        {{ faq.question }}
      </dt>
      <dd>
        {{ faq.answer }}
      </dd>
    </template>
  </dl>
```

Only in the case of DL tag, I have no choice but to suppress the warning.

Comment: This would have been my solution as well but unfortunately this gives me compilation error instead. I'm on Vue 2.7

Comment: This is exactly the case, my solution is to place a `v-if="true"` on dt and dd.

Answer (score 0):

> `<template v-for>` cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead.

You'd have to key `all elements` inside the template. If you have more than just the `<td>`, those elements would also need unique keys. Consider moving those elements into a component.

**Possible solution :**

```js
var vueStore = {
  state: {
            items: [
        {name: 'MacBook Air', price: 1000},
        {name: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1800},
        {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
        {name: 'Acer Aspire One', price: 300}
      ]    
  }
}


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    vueState: vueStore.state
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table class="table table-borderd table-striped">
    <tr>
      <template v-for="(item, index) in vueState.items">
        <td align="center" :key="index">{{ item.name }}</td>
      </template>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you add like an example if you don't mind?

Comment: Added code snippet just an example. You can use it as per your code/requirement.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for updating. The thing is I am working on a nuxtjs project with vuetify and eslint default rules are enabled. If you don't mind, can you try via `npx create-nuxt-app <app-name>` command and select `eslint` for linting and check in local?. I will be grateful

Comment: Right now I can not do that as I am working on some different project on priority. Sorry for that.

Comment: Okay. No issues.

Comment: If possible you can share the `plunkr` or `jsfiddle` link. I can check that.

Comment: I am not able to make a nuxtjs+vuetify+eslint fiddle or codesandbox or any playground :(

Comment: The question has error: <template v-for> key should be placed on the <template> tag. Your answer is the same as his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Key can not be used for two nodes in one loop. You must do something like this

```
<v-data-table :items="items">
<template v-slot:item="{ item }">
  <tr>
    <template v-for="(header, index) in headers">
      <td key="index">
        <template v-if="header.value === 'isActive'">
          <v-badge bordered content="" offset-x="-10" color="'#64b54d'" />
        </template>

        <template v-else>
          {{ item[header.value] }}
        </template>
      </td>
    </template>
  </tr>
</template>
```